# Scaling rounded corners in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I resize this object without distorting it ?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2125/how-can-i-resize-this-object-without-distorting-it)

I've created a rounded-corner triangle in Illustrator by creating a triangle and then doing Effect>Stylize>Round Corners.  Works great, except that the corners won't scale- No matter how small/big I make the triangle the corners always stay the same radius, whereas I want them to scale in proportion with the shape.

How do I take this shape and break it down into a normal, scalable path?

Thanks-

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Select the triangle and go to "Object" -> "Expand Appearance."

Answer (score 14):

Further to Jin's answer, you can maintain scaled appearance properties by checking the `Scale Strokes & Effects` box on the `Transform` palette.

[image: Transform - Scale Strokes & Effects]

Comment: I think this is a better answer than mine! I did not know this.

Comment: It's saved my day.

Comment: Also make sure that the "Scale Corners" box in the rounded corners dialog is ticked: https://snipboard.io/7ldBus.jpg