# How to resize vector masks without changing the size-ratio of round corners of it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, resize, mask

Let's say that I have a vector mask of 200px-w 150px-h rectangle with 8 px curved corners.

If I want to resize this to 100px-w 100px-h without changing the size-ratio of round corners, how do I do it without moving the each and every point of the vector one by one with pentool and re-align it with hand?

BTW I know choosing multiple points with shift and moving them together but again this also means doing it for each corner so therefore, 4 times. Is there an easier method? Such as stating the size I want and having it reshaped accordingly with corners intact.

That's what I wonder. I'm using Photoshop.

How can I resize a rounded rectangle vector mask and keep the rounded corners at their correct relative measurements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I resize this object without distorting it ?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2125/how-can-i-resize-this-object-without-distorting-it)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Photoshop CS6 Resize Rectangle with Rounded Corners](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13519/photoshop-cs6-resize-rectangle-with-rounded-corners)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're talking about Photoshop.

Although you can't scale and keep the nice corners (since PS doesn't see it as a rounded rectangle once you put it on the page), there is a tiny shorter way - Use the white arrow and drag a rectangle over 2 corners together (that's 4 dots) and move them together.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to explain, it did work. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer... you can't unless you manually move each anchor.

Answer (score 1):

As written, you're asking how to scale a vector mask without changing the proportions (that's what "without changing the size-ratio" means to me, anyway). In that case, you simply invoke `Free Transform`, hold down Shift and Alt/Option, and drag a corner handle until you get the size you need. If you need to be very accurate about the size, `F8` toggles the Info panel, which displays width and height as you drag.

If you mean that you want to scale the shape *without changing the absolute value of the corner radius*, move one side at a time using the technique in Eyal's answer: marquee-select two corners (four points) with the white arrow tool, then nudge or drag to the right dimension. Hold down Shift as you drag, to maintain an exactly vertical or horizontal movement. Drag the left- or right-most corners, then the top or bottom corners (or vice versa). Two drags and you're done.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Gilbertson. I really appreciate your help and suggestions, you have been very kind and helpful. Sorry though I can not up-vote as I do not have enough points, it says.

Answer (score 1):

if u still need it
here is a free script to change the corners so u can just scale it & redo the corners with this script
[Photoshop CS6 Resize Rectangle with Rounded Corners](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13519/photoshop-cs6-resize-rectangle-with-rounded-corners)