# Photoshop CS6 Resize Rectangle with Rounded Corners

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, cs6

This question is about Photoshop CS6. Hopefully the feature was added in this version. Before posting I looked up Google and [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2125/how-can-i-resize-this-object-without-distorting-it) and [that](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5321/how-to-resize-vector-masks-without-changing-the-size-ratio-of-round-corners-of-i) but didn't find an answer for CS6.

So the question is: Is there a feature within CS6 or a script that allows to resize a vector element with rounded corners **without using the Direct Selection Tool (white arrow tool)** and not changing the border radius? What would be great would be something like simply using the transform tool or something like a grid resize tool.

Comment: I started using [Sketch](http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/) which is great for web/UI design. Rounded rectangles are builtin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simple answer is: No.

I have asked Adobe to add the feature. If you'd like to see it, please vote here:

> [Photoshop: It would be good if the roundrect vector tool corner radius was editable during and after drawing](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/it_would_be_good_if_the_roundrect_vector_tool_corner_radius_was_editable_during_and_after_drawing)

And now some good news. David Jensen has written a nice little script to help. It's not perfect (doesn't handle multiple shapes on the one layer), but it does the trick in many situtions.

The script allows you to transform shapes (distorting them), then you can reapply the corners. You will need to remember the radius you used though.

> [image]
>
> [Rounded Rectangle Radius Resizer](http://photoshopscripts.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/rounded-rectangle-radius-resizer/)

The screenshot shows Windows, but the script also works on the Mac version of Photoshop.

Comment: This. Will save me so much time. Just resize with Free Transform Tool then run the script and BAM!

Comment: Wooop. Looks like your prayers were answered. This feature is in Creative Cloud

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround. Using the menu command Image->Image Size... (Alt+Cntl+I) scales the rounded corners with the shape. So a rounded rectangle with 50 radius corners resampled with this method to half the size will now have 25 radius corners.

Since the shape is vector it won't degrade the quality of the graphic. If you don't want to resample the entire image you can drag the shape into a new document, resample, then drag back.

Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: Hell yes. This solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

No, Photoshop doesn't have a direct feature that does this for you. You could try writing a script for this or as a work around use the shapes tool and create the shape and delete and create it again if you need to change it.

You can use the shapes tool like this:

To access it you can **press and hold** the **ellipse icon** below the black arrow icon (path selection tool) and select *rounded rectangle* and draw using it. The shapes are drawn using *paths* and you can re-size them anytime you want and even change colors and set individual styles.

Or you will have to do using the rectangular marque tool and create a rectangle and smooth it out to the required radius.

Comment: Big mistake on my part: I forgot to mention resizing rounded rectangles without altering the border radius (and like originally mentioned without using the Direct Selection Tool)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Illustrator CS6 you can create a rectangle, select your rectangle go to menu
`effect > stylize > round corners` then select the proper styling for rounded corners. Finally copy/paste as a smart object into Photoshop.

Answer (score -3):

After drawing the rectangle check on the "Show transformation Control" check box on the top..
You will get the handles to resize the rectangle..

Comment: Is this in Photoshop CC? I think I found a video of rounded corners. [Check the video on this page at 1:28](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/modify-shapes.html).