# Photoshop cc - how do i resize a box and keep the radius the same?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, cc-2014

I know there are several questions that ask this - so far the answer has been "impossible", but in one of them there was an allusion (or... illusion?) to being able to do so in the cc edition.

I have the cc edition, if only on a trial basis.

I have a shape selected - it is a white "rectangle", with a drop box and so forth. Rectangle is in quotes, because to *me* it is a rectangle, but I do not know how the rectangle was created.

As seen here:

[image]

I want to resize this (which was harder than it needed to be - i had to go to edit - free transform.

But when i drag the image, the rounded corners go bonkers! I read [in this answer - see the comments](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/13521/29390) that it should be possible to edit the corners now.

But i do not know what to press...  in the pictures i found on youtube, it looked like when i opened "properties" i should be able to see the transform options.

How do i make this simple image bigger and with a rounded corner?

Comment: I don't think a lengthy process of scaling up this box has any benefits compared to simply drawing a new one in the size you need with the radius you need. Which would only take a few seconds.

Comment: @bharal what is this `A|` symbol on you right panel for text? How do I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why your Properties options don't have the radius section.  I think Emily is on the right track, in stating that your "shape" may in fact just be a layer mask on a filled layer.  My Properties option box has a separate "Shape" section in it (see below).
[image: shape]

I would just create an actual shape and scrap what you have there with that mask, but if you do insist on using what you already have, the best way that I can see to resize it and still maintain your radii would be by moving the points on either side of each radius.  I have to disagree with Emily here, I ALWAYS avoid rasterizing - at all costs.

Use the `Direct Selection Tool` for this, as pictured below:
[image: tool]

Select this group of `Anchor Points` to adjust the rectangle's size horizontally.  Hold down the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key, to drag the points in a straight line.
[image: horiz]

vice-versa for vertically
[image: vert]

Like I said, I always try to avoid rasterizing and instead prefer to work with shapes, smart objects, and layer masks.  This keeps everything scalable and is also a non-destructive way of working.

Comment: No properties because it is a *shape layer* and not a *vector layer*. They are different in terms of editing capabilities. But this is an excellent method to resize shape layers and what *had* to be done before vector layers were introduced.

Comment: Yea, @Scott, I realized the reason for them not seeing the same options as I did was because of that, which is why I went in and edited my answer a bit. I'm old school, myself.  There were no vector layers, when I was teaching myself this stuff, so this method is what I've always known.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Try rasterizing the layer. There looks to be a mask, not necessarily a shape. I hate the "shape" tool and prefer the "marquee" tool > adding a new layer > fill with color.